# Iterate through a list with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, list, dictionary, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm using BeautifulSoup4 to build a JSON formatted list that contains:
'title', 'company', 'location', 'date posted' and 'link' from a public Linkedin Job search, I have already this formatted the way I want it, however it's only listing one of the job listings from the page, and am looking to iterate through each job in the page, in this same format.

For example, am trying to achieve this:

```
[{'title': 'Job 1', 'company': 'company 1.', 'location': 'sunny side, California', 'date posted': '2 weeks ago', 'link': 'example1.com'}]

[{'title': 'Job 2', 'company': 'company 2.', 'location': 'runny side, California', 'date posted': '2 days ago', 'link': 'example2.com'}]
```

I've tried changing lines 48, 52, 56, 60, and 64 from contents.find to contents.findAll, however, it returns everything and not in the order am trying to achieve.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

def strip_tags(html):
    s = MLStripper()
    s.feed(html)
    return s.get_data()


def search_website(url):
    # Search HTML Page
    result = requests.get(url)
    content = result.content

soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'html.parser')

# Job List
jobs = []

for contents in soup.find_all('body'):
    # Title
    title = contents.find('h3', attrs={'class': 'result-card__title ''job-result-card__title'})
    formatted_title = strip_tags(str(title))

    # Company
    company = contents.find('h4', attrs={'class': 'result-card__subtitle job-result-card__subtitle'})
    formatted_company = strip_tags(str(company))

    # Location
    location = contents.find('span', attrs={'class': 'job-result-card__location'})
    formatted_location = strip_tags(str(location))

    # Date Posted
    posted = contents.find('time', attrs={'class': 'job-result-card__listdate'})
    formatted_posted = strip_tags(str(posted))

    # Apply Link
    links = contents.find('a', attrs={'class': 'result-card__full-card-link'})
    formatted_link = (links.get('href'))

    # Add a new compiled job to our dict
    jobs.append({'title': formatted_title,
                 'company': formatted_company,
                 'location': formatted_location,
                 'date posted': formatted_posted,
                 'link': formatted_link
                 })

# Return our jobs
return jobs


link = ("https://www.linkedin.com/jobs/search/currentJobId=1396095018&distance=25&f_E=3%2C4&f_LF=f_AL&geoId=102250832&keywords=software%20engineer&location=Mountain%20View%2C%20California%2C%20United%20States")


print(search_website(link))
```

I expect the output to look like

```
[{'title': 'x', 'company': 'x', 'location': 'x', 'date posted': 'x', 'link': 'x'}] [{'title': 'x', 'company': 'x', 'location': 'x', 'date posted': 'x', 'link': 'x'}] +..
```

Output when switched to FindAll returns:

```
[{'title': 'x''x''x''x''x', 'company': 'x''x''x''x''x', 'location': 'x''x''x''x', 'date posted': 'x''x''x''x', 'link': 'x''x''x''x'}]
```

Comment: I'm confused: what is the original url (for the "public Linkedin Job search" ) used in `result = requests.get(url)`?

Comment: Sorry I had written this at a late time and forgot to include that. https://www.linkedin.com/jobs/search/?distance=25&f_E=2%2C3&f_JT=F&f_LF=f_AL&geoId=102250832&keywords=software%20engineer&location=Mountain%20View%2C%20California%2C%20United%20States It's also in the link variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a simplified version of your code, but it should get you there:

```
result = requests.get('https://www.linkedin.com/jobs/search/?distance=25&f_E=2%2C3&f_JT=F&f_LF=f_AL&geoId=102250832&keywords=software%20engineer&location=Mountain%20View%2C%20California%2C%20United%20States')

soup = bs(result.content, 'html.parser')

# Job List
jobs = []

for contents in soup.find_all('body'):
    # Title
    title = contents.find('h3', attrs={'class': 'result-card__title ''job-result-card__title'})        

    # Company
    company = contents.find('h4', attrs={'class': 'result-card__subtitle job-result-card__subtitle'})        

    # Location
    location = contents.find('span', attrs={'class': 'job-result-card__location'})        

    # Date Posted
    posted = contents.find('time', attrs={'class': 'job-result-card__listdate'})        

    # Apply Link
    link = contents.find('a', attrs={'class': 'result-card__full-card-link'})

    # Add a new compiled job to our dict
    jobs.append({'title': title.text,
                 'company': company.text,
                 'location': location.text,
                 'date posted': posted.text,
                 'link': link.get('href')
                 })

    for job in jobs:
        print(job)
```

Output:

`{'title': 'Systems Software Engineer - Controls', 'company': 'Blue River Technology', 'location': 'Sunnyvale, California', 'date posted': '1 day ago', 'link': 'https://www.linkedin.com/jobs/view/systems-software-engineer-controls-at-blue-river-technology-1380882942?position=1&pageNum=0&trk=guest_job_search_job-result-card_result-card_full-click'}`

Comment: Thank you, this is a much better method than my previous string replace arg.